# Question about differentiability of the inverse homeomorphism

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

**Theorem (differentiability of the inverse homeomorphism):**
Let $f:U\to V$ be a differentiable homeomorphism between the open sets $U,V\subset\mathbb{R}^m$. If, for some $x\in U$, the derivative $f'(x):\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is an invertible operator, then the inverse homeomorphism $g = f^{-1}:V\to U$ is differentiable at the point $f(x)$, with $f'(f(x)) = [f'(x)]^{-1}$

**Proof:**

**If $x, x+v\in U$, we write $f(x) = y, f(x+v) = y+w$. Then:
$$w = f(x+v)-f(x) = f'(x)\cdot v + r(v)$$
$$v = g(f(x+v))-g(f(x)) = g(y+w)-g(y)$$
In order to prove that $f'(x)^{-1}$ is the derivative of $g$ at the point $y$, write:**

$$g(y+w)-g(y) = f'(x)^{-1}\cdot w + s(w)$$

and let's show that $\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{s(w)}{|w|} = 0$. Then, by the equality above, and the expressions of $v$ and $w$:

$v = f'(x)^{-1}[f'(x)\cdot v + r(v)] + s(w)$

that is

$v = v + f'(x)^{-1}\cdot r(v) + s(w)$

where

$s(w) = -f'(x)^{-1}\cdot r(v)$, therefore $\frac{s(w)}{|w|} = -f'(x)^{-1}\cdot\frac{r(v)}{|v|}\cdot \frac{|v|}{|w|}$, that is:

$$\frac{s(w)}{|w|} = f'(x)^{-1}\cdot\frac{r(v)}{|v|}\cdot\frac{|v|}{|f(x+v)-f(x)|}$$

When $w\to 0$, we have $v\to 0$ by the continuity of $g$, therefore $\frac{r(v)}{|v|}\to 0$. Also, by [this theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2288505/fu-to-mathbbrn-is-of-class-c1-if-for-a-in-u-u-open-fa-is-i), there exists $\delta>0$ and $c>0$ such that $|v|<\delta$ implies

$$|f(x+v)-f(x)|\ge c|v|$$

therefore:

$$\frac{|v|}{|f(x+v)-f(x)|}\le \frac{1}{c}$$

therefore

$$\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{s(w)}{|w|} = 0$$

**Question**:

I didn't understand the choices for $v$ and $w$. I understood the entire algebraic manipulation, but it seems like magic to me. Could somebody explain me this in a better way?

Comment: There are no choices for $v$ and $w$ beyond their relationship to each other in the first line. Essentially $v$ is $\Delta x$ and $w$ is $\Delta y$. They're the variables being taken to $0$ in the limits.

Comment: @aes could you explain this better? I cannot visualize